# Changes History & Auto-Save in Mathematica & Others

Tags: mathematica

Does anybody know of way to save changes history ?

In Wolfram Mathematica but also for other type of documents ?

Comment: Maybe you should try using some sort of [version control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2816628/421225). Personally, I use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) for most things now (including Mathematica notebooks).

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* documents are ASCII text files, so they are friendly to all version control systems like [git](http://git-scm.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [bazar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/), [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/), etc. I personally use and recommend git. One of its advantages is its fast performance which is important for the potentially large files that *Mathematica* generates.

Also you may be interested in when a particular cell was changed. Each cell contains a property named [CellChangeTimes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellChangeTimes.html) with that information.

Lastly, if you want a very simple solution is to store your file in [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com), or. use a Mac with [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete answer over at mathematica.stackexchange
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5518/388

In summary any text source control will work about that same since mathematica's notebook file format is out side the working assumptions of all common source control systems.

Also pointed out as comment in the linked question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816628/version-control-of-mathematica-notebooks